# Android DateTime comparison with Date Only precision

Tags: android, date, datetime

I find a number of references on how to compare 2 dates, but they all seem to compare the DateTime rather than the Dates by themselves.

I am saving off a LastUpdate into SQLite which requires it to be a DateTime.
At a later time I am retrieving that value as a String then converting it back to an Android Date (which is really a DateTime).

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date LastDate = formatter.parse(LastUpdate);
```

Then I am comparing it to Today (which is also a DateTime)

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

I was trying to use

```
today.compareTo(LastDate)
```

But it seems as though the precision of that goes down to the Time part.
Meaning that even if the Dates are the same, but one time is different, the result is either + or - based on the Time part.

I only want to work with a precision of a full Date, ignoring the Time part.

How can I get that level of precision?

Thanks

Comment: One option might be to convert each date to the start of that date and then compare them, so even if it does go down to the time if they are both 00:00 the comparison will work like you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.   Your answer and Markus' below both say the same thing AND, while it is a work-around kludge to get around bad database architecture (field type limitations),  that works for me.   Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `isToday(long when)` in the [DateUtils.class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#isToday(long)). It just compares the year, month and the monthDay. If that's not what you are looking for you could set your dates to midnight before you compare them like:

```
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    today.set(HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    today.set(MINUTE, 0);
    today.set(SECOND, 0);
    today.set(MILLISECOND, 0);

    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.setTime(formatter.parse(LastUpdate));
    date.set(HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    date.set(MINUTE, 0);
    date.set(SECOND, 0);
    date.set(MILLISECOND, 0);

    today.compareTo(date)
```