# Android DateTime comparison with Date Only precision #2

Tags: android, datetime

I thought that I had a workable approach, but I am not getting the expected results.

I originally asked how to compare 2 DateTime's with a Date precision - ignoring the Time element.
[Android DateTime comparison with Date Only precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405833/android-datetime-comparison-with-date-only-precision)

I put that approach into effect, and the Debug is showing the variables set as intended, but the comparison is still failing.

I am beginning with a String representation of a LastUpdate.

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
// Set Time to 1:00am so as to eliminate Time from comparison
today.setHours(1); ;
today.setMinutes(0);
today.setSeconds(0);

LastUpdateStr = getResult;  // Example results "2015-12-22 08:24:41"
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Date LastDate = null;
        try {
            LastDate = formatter.parse(LastUpdateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    // Set Time to 1:00am so as to eliminate Time from comparison
    LastDate.setHours(1); ;
    LastDate.setMinutes(0);
    LastDate.setSeconds(0);
```

At this point I SHOULD have 2 DateTimes (today & LastDate) which have the same Time element so as to eliminate it from the comparison.

However when I attempt to compare the 2 dates I do not get expected results.
If I use

```
LastDate.compareTo(today);
```

I should expect the results to be:
0  -- if Dates the same
-1 -- if today earlier than LastDate
1  -- if LastDate earlier than today

And if I do the following

```
LastDate.before(today);
```

I should expect the results to be:
**TRUE** if LastDate earlier than today
**FALSE** if not

But neither of those comparison methods are giving the expected results.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android DateTime comparison with Date Only precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405833/android-datetime-comparison-with-date-only-precision)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I still am not sure why the above did not work, but I found an approach that seems to work.

Instead of using the  **.setHour(1)  .setMinute(0)   .setSeconds(0)**  approach I changed it.

I am now using:

```
Date today0 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
Date today = new Date(today0.getYear(), today0.getMonth(), Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd", today0))));

LastUpdateStr = getResult();  // Example results "2015-12-22 08:24:41"
LastDate0 = formatter.parse(LastUpdateStr);
Date LastDate = new Date(LastDate0.getYear(), LastDate0.getMonth(), Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd", LastDate0))));
```

Where my previous approach did NOT work, that new approach results in Dates that work successfully in the comparison:

```
LastDate.after(today);
```

Thanks